# how to show float value of decimal.Decimal during delve mozilla rr(record-replay) replay session

Tags: go, delve

How can we easily see the float value of decimal.Decimal value in delve session.
especially in `dlv replay` session recorded by mozilla rr.

```
(dlv) args
underlyingPx = github.com/shopspring/decimal.Decimal {value: ("*math/big.Int")(0xc00101cca0), exp: 3}

(dlv) p underlyingPx
github.com/shopspring/decimal.Decimal {
    value: *math/big.Int {
        neg: false,
        abs: math/big.nat len: 1, cap: 1, [8],},
    exp: 3,}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the delve tool and refined the `p` command:

https://github.com/whunmr/delve/commit/14a12a076b3626b8a36046793508785239a42f55

demo:

```
(dlv) p im
github.com/shopspring/decimal.Decimal {
    value: *math/big.Int {
        neg: false,
        abs: math/big.nat len: 2, cap: 7, [4670227136653295616,10618058790999],},
    exp: -33,}

value: 0.19586861307716508    <---- this is the added output
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code of Decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal/blob/master/decimal.go#L715) there is a method to receive this information:

```
// Float64 returns the nearest float64 value for d and a bool indicating
// whether f represents d exactly.
// For more details, see the documentation for big.Rat.Float64
func (d Decimal) Float64() (f float64, exact bool) {
    return d.Rat().Float64()
}
```

In provided example it will be enough to just call this method:

```
(dlv) p underlyingPx.Float64()
```

Comment: unfortunately, we can't call methods during mozilla rr replay session of `dlv replay`

Comment: failure outputs:
(dlv) p body.Amount.Float64()
Command failed: function calls not allowed without using 'call'

Comment: @whunmr, can you try `(dlv) call underlyingPx.Float64()`? If it will works, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: not works with `call`, output is "Command failed: unsupported packet $G000000000000000060... during registers write"

Comment: I think maybe the doable approach is parse the `p` command output using a python script: github.com/shopspring/decimal.Decimal {
 value: *math/big.Int {
  neg: false,
  abs: math/big.nat len: 1, cap: 1, [10],},
 exp: 0,}

Comment: `(dlv) call underlyingPx->Float64()`?

Comment: IMHO it's not possible to call something in mozilla rr session, because it's need definite state to  do replay.